# Why does not mail displayed at sent folder?

Tags: perl, smtp

I am using Net::SMTP to send mail with Perl
I am sending mail with below code and I see that mail reached to recipient xxx@mail.com

```
my $smtp = Net::SMTP->new($server,
                 Port    => $port,
             Timeout => 10,
             Debug   => 1);
$smtp->auth($user, $password);

$smtp->mail('sender@mail.com');*
$smtp->to('xxx@mail.com');
$smtp->data();
$smtp->datasend("Subject: $subject\n\r\n\r".
                          $body);*
$connection->dataend();
```

But when I went to mailbox of sender account (sender@mail.com), I dont see this mail at SENT folder.
How can I supply this?

Comment: You would have to use IMAP (or whatever) to place the message in the folder on that IMAP (or whatever) server.

Comment: You could BCC the sender to place a copy in his inbox.

Comment: @ikegami you should post that as an answer. Folders are only for incoming messages, not sent ones, and IMAP and SMTP are independent services.

Comment: @Stuart Watt, go ahead and take the credit. I gotta run

Answer (score 2):

As @ikegami said in their comment above, you would need to use an IMAP client to do this. SMTP is only used for sending messages, IMAP is used to manage message storage. Put simply, SMTP is used to actually send the message to the recipient. IMAP is used to manage a user's mail folders, storing messages for later access. IMAP is what drives access stored messages in common email-reading clients.

There area few IMAP clients in Perl, for example: [Mail::IMAPClient](https://metacpan.org/release/Mail-IMAPClient). IMAP is significantly more complex than SMTP (the 'S' stands for 'simple' after all) but once you have managed to wade through all the authentication systems (and this will be most of the work), there is an `append` method documented at [Mail::IMAPClient#Mailbox-Control-Methods](https://metacpan.org/pod/release/PLOBBES/Mail-IMAPClient-3.35/lib/Mail/IMAPClient.pod#Mailbox-Control-Methods) that probably does what you want:

`my $uid = $imap->append($folder,$msg_text) 
                or die "Could not append: $@\n";`

You can use this to store a sent copy of the message, in the sending user's IMAP account. Obviously, the authentication you set up will need to permit access to that.

The module is fairly well documented and has plenty of examples.

Answer (score 0):

I will use below command

my $uid = $imap->append($folder,$msg_text) or die "Could not append: $@\n";

What is name of sent folder? What is value of scalr $folder?  SENT, OUTBOX